# Map is not loading when i am adding shortcode to page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In custom template there is a map on the top of page and then there is contact form, when I remove the contact form, map is showing but when I put short code in place of contact form then map is not loading.

Comment: It must be jquery conflict issue. check your console and fix errors.

Comment: yes the error is "jQuery(...).CustomMap is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue.

```
jQuery.noConflict(true);
```